# django loop static files directory

Tags: python, django

Iam trying to loop thru images in static/folder. I can loop thru images in main 'static' folder but when i put them in 'static/folder' iam not sure how to do it in html.

my html lines(works when img in main 'static' folder)

```
{% for file in files %}
    <img src=" {% static file %}" height="800">
    <p>File name:{{ file }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

my views.py

```
def album1(request):
    images = '/home/michal/PycharmProjects/Family/gallery/static/'
    files = os.listdir(os.path.join(images))
    context = {'files': files}
    return render(request, 'gallery/album1/main.html', context)
```

If i change views to:

```
def album1(request):
    images = '/home/michal/PycharmProjects/Family/gallery/static/'
    files = os.listdir(os.path.join(images, 'folder'))
    context = {'files': files}
    return render(request, 'gallery/album1/main.html', context)
```

It loops filenames in 'static/folder/' as expected, but then i cant figure out how to change it in html ,as its adding file names to:  /static/{{ file }} instead to /static/folder/{{ file }}.
I think iam missing something or something need changing in load static on this particular page?

```
{% load static %}                 # either here 
<img src=" {% static file %}">    # or here?
```

Answer (score 0):

You prepend the filenames with the name of the folder:

```
from os.path import join

def album1(request):
    images = '/home/michal/PycharmProjects/Family/gallery/static/'
    files = os.listdir(join(images, 'folder'))
    context = {'files': [join(folder, file) for file in files]}
    return render(request, 'gallery/album1/main.html', context)
```

You can slice in the template with the [**`|slice`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{% for file in files|slice:':21' %}
    <img src=" {% static file %}" height="800">
    <p>File name:{{ file }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But it is more efficient to do this in the view, since you save cycles on by performing less `join` calls, and furthermore the templates are less efficient than Python code.

Comment: It worked but now I have problem with selecting range for files to be displayed. 
Before I was able to do:

    {% for file in files[0:21] %}


but now I have: "Could not parse the remainder: '[0:21]' from 'files[0:21]' ". Trying to find my way around this :)

Comment: for time being i got it sorted by doing "{'files': [join(folder, file) for file in files[:21]]}" ,its not great but will do for a time being . Will be much better to declare range in html, as it would get rid of flooding views.py with new functions. will keep trying

Comment: @Michal_S: that is logical, since Django templates do not allow slicing. It is also better to do this in the view, since it is more efficient. If you really want to do it in the template, you can make use of the `|slice:` template filter. See edit.